# rails 5 assert_select fails in test, because sort order is different between model and test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails5 – testing problem - i am developing a web app in rails 5 beta3.
I want to test if a link is produced on the page. The link does show on the development site when I run 'rails s', but the test fails. So i put byebug to see where it goes wrong. UPDATE: I found that the user controller is sending users sorted by 'id DESC' but the test is using default sort so it matches the first try by accident, then fails on the second.

I cannot get the test to run with anything other than default sort due to errors. adding related code from model and controller.

'Rake test' passes on first user, but fails on second user.

> FAIL ["test_index_including_pagination", UsersIndexTest, 202.31457826300175]
>   test_index_including_pagination#UsersIndexTest (202.31s)
>   Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/205739844"]", found 0..
>   Expected 0 to be >= 1.
>   test/integration/users_index_test.rb:16:in 'block (2 levels) in '
>   test/integration/users_index_test.rb:14:in `block in '

When I try to use code from controller index action I get error. Demonstrated with byebug output:

```
(byebug) User.search(term: "al", page: 1 ) 
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
nil
```

GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.0.0.beta3'
ruby "2.3.0"
gem 'puma', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0.0.beta1'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0.beta2'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.4.1'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.1', group: :doc
gem 'argon2', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.0.4'
gem 'will_paginate',           '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.10'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6.3'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', '~> 8.2.4'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.6'
  gem 'spring', '~> 1.7.1'
end
group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest', '~> 5.8.4'
gem 'minitest-rails', :github => 'blowmage/minitest-rails', :branch => 'rails5'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1.8'
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

TESTCODE:

```
  test "index including pagination" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    User.paginate(page: 2).each do |user|
      byebug
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)
    end
  end
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:term], params[:page])
end
```

MODEL:

```
 def self.search(term, current_page)
   if term
     page(current_page).where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%").order('id DESC')
   else
     page(current_page).order('id DESC') 
   end
 end

 def self.search(term, page)
    if term
      where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{term}%".downcase).paginate(page: page, per_page: 5).order('id DESC')
    else
      paginate(page: page, per_page: 5).order('id DESC') 
    end
 end
```

Comment: When do you run test with byebug  get you: `assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)` ?

Comment: in byebug, first time, finds user link correctly, but after 'continue' it fail to find next user because user.id is different in rendered page and user.each loop.

Comment: but are there links to other users presented in body?

Comment: yes, each page has 5 users links, but the links are not all the ones expected by the test because of the sort order is different

Comment: is that the error what they are in different order?

Comment: the error comes from the five presented by the view/controller are not the same five presented by the test.

Comment: I noticed you were using attr_digest previously and that it wasn't compatible with Argon2 v1.0.0. I've updated the gem and the rails5 branch. It nows supports Argon2 v1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the test was not passing the hashed values properly to the model.

The original test code below provided the wrong set of users to the test so I got a failure:

```
User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
```

Adding sort to the test as follows produced a strange error indicating that only one value was passed when two were expected. The code I used was:

```
User.search(term: 'al', page: 1).each do |user|
```

Fixed the problem by changing test code to:

```
User.search('al', 1).each do |user|
```

The test now passes without errors. It seems that writing the test with hashes (term: 'al', page: 1) caused the error.